# Trivial off-site link answer converted to comment but answer not deleted

Tags: bug

According to [Answer appears automatically converted as a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955) on meta.se:

> Trivial answers containing a link to another question in the network are automatically converted to comments on the question

I came across this answer on dba.se:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244318

> I solved that issue by referring below link. stackoverflow.com/a/57307231/11701617

...together with an apparently duplicate comment:

[`SHOW EVENTS` fail with `Error Code: 1545. Failed to open mysql.event`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206327/show-events-fail-with-error-code-1545-failed-to-open-mysql-event/244318#comment482122_206327)

The user has 1 rep (so can 't comment directly) and there have been no moderation actions on this Q & A, so I can only assume the automatic conversion process was responsible.

Why wasn't the answer deleted when the comment was created?

- The comment has a timestamp of 2019-08-01 10:50:15Z
- The answer has a timestamp of 2019-08-01 10:51:44Z (later)

There are no deleted answers at the time of writing, and that user has taken to actions beyond that one answer and comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that the answer is *newer* than the comment and answers automatically converted this way don't actually leave any deleted answers behind, what likely happened here is that the user **posted *two* such answers**.

The first one was automatically converted into a comment. After this happened the user tried again, possibly wondering what happened to his answer. But this time the answer *wasn't* converted, likely because it doesn't actually contain a link (it's missing the `https://`).